# Inconclusive second derivative test at (0,0) for $x^{4} + y^{4} - 2x^{2} - 2y^{2} +4xy $

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Second derivative test is inconclusive here , given f( x, y) is

$x^{4} + y^{4} - 2x^{2} - 2y^{2} +4xy $

At (0,0) how do i check nature ? Also i would like to know general tactics when things  like these happen .Thank You

Comment: Do you know what is Hessian?

Comment: @StefanGyürki its zero

Comment: I think it is -16.

Comment: You are right.. sorry, I was computing by heart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly $f(0,0)=0$. What is the sign of the function value if you are going from $(0,0)$ along the line $x=0$? If you are making a small $\varepsilon>0$ step from $(0,0)$ in that direction, then you have $f(0,\varepsilon)=\varepsilon^4-2\varepsilon^2=\varepsilon^2(\varepsilon^2-1)<0$. At the second step, you can go from $(0,0)$ along the line $y=x$ and follow the values on it: $f(\varepsilon, \varepsilon)=2\varepsilon^4>0$. Thus, if you are going in the first direction, you are going downwards on the graph of the function, while if you are going along the other line you are going upwards from zero. Therefore $(0,0)$ is a saddle point of $f(x,y)$.

Comment: please vote my question so that i may have enough reputations to vote your answer .Thanks